# python selenium sending keys to readonly text box

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to send keys to the below field using below python selenium code

```html
<input type="text" name="date_startDateSql" readonly="" class="EditableRequiredField" onfocus="setday(this)">
```

Selenium Python Code :

`element=driver.find_element_by_name('date_startDateSql')
 element.send_keys('12/10/2017')`

I am not getting any error or exception but not able to send keys into this element.I am new to python selenium and would appreciate if someone could advise how to send keys to the fields that are readonly.

Comment: If it is read-only field then you might not be able to type text there manually? If yes then via selenium also you can't do. Are you able to type text there manually?

Comment: Nope @Akhtar I am not able to type text manually.. but when I remove "readonly" from html page, I am able to type. Is there a way to remove "readonly " property of the field using webdriver ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the *readonly* attribute of your input before sending keys :

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("date_startDateSql")[0].removeAttribute("readonly")')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I am getting below error                                        selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: document.getElementByName is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Adapted to grab via element id but works great, thanks! `driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("id_name_here").removeAttribute("readonly")')`

Answer (score 3):

This worked perfectly!

If there aren't multiple elements with the same ID, you can use:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("ELEMENT ID").removeAttribute("readonly")')
```