# How to fix a datepicker in python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make an Auto-Reg bot with python and selenium. I'm getting the most things to work, as they aren't that hard. But atm i'm stuck at a datepicker. The code is able to open the date-box but it doesn't select a date. Another problem is, you cant write anything in the date box, you HAVE to select a date in the date box.

I tried various methods i found on stackoverflow but nothing works for this site.

Site: https://mobilepanel2.nielsen.com/enrol/home?l=de_de&pid=9

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
b = webdriver.Chrome(r'''C:\Users\Florian\PycharmProjects\Auto_Reg\chromedriver''')
b.get('https://mobilepanel2.nielsen.com/enrol/home?l=de_de&pid=9')
b.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='platform']/option[contains(text(),'Android')]").click()
b.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='deviceType']/option[contains(text(),'Smartphone')]").click()
b.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Männlich')]").click()
## until here, everything works fine 

select = Select(b.find_element_by_name('birthDate'))
select.select_by_visible_text("13")
```

Comment: The hard way to do it would be IMO to click the Calendar icon, then click through the date you want to input. The easy way would be to use your Network tab inside your browser inspect and see what the site sends when you hit Submit on a set of good data, then just use requests or any other library to just send your data without clicking stuff. Another idea could be to remove the `readonly` property of the input field wih a javascript call and just force text into it.

Comment: Update: how to remove `readonly` property of datepicker field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012126/python-selenium-sending-keys-to-readonly-text-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# click calendar to appear
browser.find_element_by_id('birthDateCalendar').click()

# get calendar elements
calendar = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr/td')

# click selected day
selection = '15'
for item in calendar:
    day = item.get_attribute("innerText")
    if day == selection:
        item.click()
```

Comment: A more efficient way to do this is to use the XPath `//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//td[.='15']`. That will return the specific element you are looking for so you don't have to loop through all calendar elements. Also using `//*` looks through all elements on the page. You should specify the element when you know what it's going to be, e.g. in this case `DIV`.

Comment: I would suggest that you wrap this whole thing in method that takes the desired date as a parameter. That way you can just call `set_date('15')` or whatever and make your code more DRY.